# C# pressionar tecla múltiplas vezes

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Estou usando c# para navegar enttet botões e textbox de uma página.
Para isso uso a tecla TAB porque os nomes dos objetos da página são dinâmicos,cada vez que o site atualiza o id e class mudam.

Estou usando a seguinte sintaxe:

```
pg.findElement(By.Name("nome_ficticio")).sendKeys(keys.Tab + keys.Tab + keys.Tab....)
```

Teria como eu mandar o Tab ser pressionado repetidas vezes de maneira mais eficiente?

Comment: Apresente mais do seu código e a estrutura da página que está tentando interagir... talvez seja o caso de mudar o seu seletor ao invés de ficar "dando" tab...

Comment: Já tentou guardar o conteúdo numa sessão ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Teria como eu mandar o Tab ser pressionado repetidas vezes de maneira mais eficiente?

Sim, você pode fazer isso criando uma **Extension Method** e um laço `for`.

Ex:

```cs
static class IWebElementExtensions
{
    public static void SendKeysRepeat(this IWebElement element, string text, int qty)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < qty; i++)
            element.SendKeys(text);
    }
}
```

Uso:

```cs
pg.findElement(By.Name("nome_ficticio")).SendKeysRepeat(keys.Tab, 3);
```

OBS: Aparentemente você não está usando C# e sim Java. Se for, você pode tentar dar uma olhada como se faz Extension Method no Java através do link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359979/java-equivalent-to-c-sharp-extension-methods